# How to find the elements present in a list from another list

Tags: list, scala

I have two lists like this

```
val list1=List("abc","def","mnp","wpr")

val list2=List("bc","de","pr")
```

I want to get a new list which will check  if the items of `list1` contains items of `list2`

eg-`"abc"` in `list1` contains `"bc"` from `list2`

`"def"` in `list1` contains `"de"` from `list2`

`"wpr"` in `list1` contains `"pr"` from `list2`

The output should be a list like this

```
List("abc","def","wpr")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with one-liner like here:

```
scala> val list1 = List("abc", "def", "mnp", "wpr")
list1: List[String] = List(abc, def, mnp, wpr)

scala> val list2 = List("bc", "de", "pr")
list2: List[String] = List(bc, de, pr)

scala> list1.filter(x => list2.exists(y => x.contains(y)))
res0: List[String] = List(abc, def, wpr)
```

It works fine for small `list2` lists and small strings, but has complexity `O(n1 * n2 * m1 * m2)` for the worst case, where `n1` and `n2` - sizes of lists, `m1` and `m2` - sizes of strings in corresponding lists. So, for long `list2` lists or/and long strings, please, consider using more efficient algorithms, like [Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick).

Comment: this should work.In my case list2 is very small i.e max it could go upto 10 elements

Comment: Can you please take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249758/how-can-i-get-the-elements-of-list-using-listbuffer