# How can I get the elements of list using ListBuffer

Tags: list, scala

I am facing a very weird problem while getting elements of a list

Below is the piece of code where I am passing arguments as "bc" and "mn"

```
val list1 = List("abc", "def", "mnp")
    val list2 = List(args(0), args(1))
    val header1=list1.filter(x => list2.exists(y => x.contains(y)))
    println(header1)
```

Output-List("abc","mnp")

I am trying to do it in a different way (by passing the same arguments)but getting an empty List

```
val list1 = List("abc", "def", "mnp")
    //val list2 = List(args(0), args(1))
    val ipList1= new ListBuffer[Any]
    for(i <- 0 to 1){
      ipList1 +=args(i)
    }
    val list2=ipList1.toList
    println(list2)
    val header1=list1.filter(x => list2.exists(y => x.contains(y)))
    println(header1)
```

Output-List(bc, mn)

List()-->This is the empty List I am getting

Can Someone please tell where I am doing it wrong and How to make it right?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `x.contains(y)` does not mean what you think it means. `String` has a `contains` method that checks whether another `String` is a substring of this `String`. But in your code `y` doesn't have type `String`, but type `Any`. So the `contains` method of `String` isn't called. It's the `contains` method of [`WrappedString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html#contains[A1%3E:A](elem:A1):Boolean) which treats the `String` `x` as though it's a `Seq[Char]`. That method doesn't check whether any substring is equal to `y` but whether any *character* is equal to `y`.

The solution, obviously, is to use a `ListBuffer[String]`.

Comment: @Jasper-M....Yes Learnt that in a hard way...but thank you for the explaintation

Comment: Yeah... would be less painful if `contains` could be more typesafe.

Comment: I tend to prefer writing `containsSlice` to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a **ListBuffer[Any]** thus the elements lost their type information from **String** to **Any** and apparently that changes the semantics of the code.

You may either do this:

```
val ipList1 = new ListBuffer[String]
for (i <- 0 to 1) {
  ipList1 += args(i).toString
}
val list2 = ipList1.toList
```

Or even better just:

```
val list2 = args.slice(0, 2).toList
```

Comment: @Miguel the second one is not working.I just found the only problem was val ipList1 = new ListBuffer[Any].After I changed it to String the code worked properly

Comment: @Nils May you describe what _"is not working"_ means? Compile error or produces a different result? Also are `args` the arguments passed to the main?

Comment: @Miguel val list2 = args.slice(0, 2).toList this still gives an empty List..However the first solution gives the correct result

Comment: @Nils what is the type of `args`?

Comment: @Miguel types are String only